# Should I mention competition participation on CV or open application?

Tags: resume

I have a master's degree on maths. On college I took part national mathematical competitions with average results. Should I mention it on my CV or in an open application?

Comment: What were the entry requirements?

Answer (score 0):

It cannot harm to add as an "extra-curricular" activity. I would not make a big deal of it, ~I have used national mathematics competitions on my CV, but because I won them or came high. for example:

Extra Curricular Achievements:

- School Hockey Team Captain (2014-2015)
- Gold Awarded in British Mathematical Olympiad (2013)
- Gold Duke of Edinburgh Award (2013)